# How to overlay segmentation result with another image?

Tags: python, pytorch, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

This is my input image

[image: Image without segmentation]

I have this code to overlay the segmentation from input image with color

```py
# sample execution (requires torchvision)
from PIL import Image
from torchvision import transforms
input_image = Image.open("samping.JPG")
input_image = input_image.convert("RGB")
preprocess = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
])

input_tensor = preprocess(input_image)
input_batch = input_tensor.unsqueeze(0) # create a mini-batch as expected by the model

# move the input and model to GPU for speed if available
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    input_batch = input_batch.to('cuda')
    model.to('cuda')

with torch.no_grad():
    output = model(input_batch)['out'][0]
output_predictions = output.argmax(0)

# create a color pallette, selecting a color for each class
palette = torch.tensor([2 ** 25 - 1, 2 ** 15 - 1, 2 ** 21 - 1])
colors = torch.as_tensor([i for i in range(21)])[:, None] * palette
colors = (colors % 255).numpy().astype("uint8")

# plot the semantic segmentation predictions of 21 classes in each color
r = Image.fromarray(output_predictions.byte().cpu().numpy()).resize(input_image.size)
r.putpalette(colors)
```

And then i have this result : This is my segmented image overlay with color:
[image: Segmented image with color]

But, i want to overlay/change the color with another image, for the example this image

[image: Image used to overlay]

Result image that I want

[image: Segmented image that i want]
Change the segmented plate (color) into my logo, how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to SO, confuseman!

[OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) is a computer vision library that works really nicely for these kinds of tasks. You can install it with `pip install opencv-python`. In a nutshell, here are the steps required:

1. Figure out where the black pixels are located.

[image]

2. Figure out where the largest chunk of black pixels exists, by converting them into contours then calculating their individual sizes. (notice the few black pixels hanging out in the back on the right side, highlighted in green)

[image]

3. Find the rotated rectangle that most closely matches the largest contour.

[image]

4. Resize the overlay image and rotate it. Create a pad around the overlay image so that it doesn't cut off when you rotate it.

[image] [image: right arrow] [image]

<sup>(image used is [Gary Larson's "Cow Tools"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cow_Tools), I used a tall image to showcase the scaling property)</sup>

5. Paste the resulting overlay image on top of the original image. Make sure to take the pad into account when calculating the position, otherwise it will go southeast of where you intended to go.

[image]

<sup>Voila!</sup>

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load images
img = cv2.imread('stack_car.jpg')
# Replace the overlay image with your own,
# for now I will use Gary Larson's "Cow Tools" because it showcases the
# scaling property, what a fantastic image though
overlay_img = cv2.imread('cow_tools.png', -1) 

# Convert image to grayscale for easier thresholding
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Threshold the image
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 1, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# Show the threshold image
cv2.imshow('Threshold Image', thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Find contours
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Draw contours on a copy of the image for visualization
img_contours = img.copy()
cv2.drawContours(img_contours, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
cv2.imshow('Contours', img_contours)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Find the largest chunk of black pixels
max_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# Get a rotated box around the largest contour
rotated_rect = cv2.minAreaRect(max_contour)

# draw the rotated rectangle on a copy of the image for visualization
img_rotated_rect = img.copy()
box = cv2.boxPoints(rotated_rect)
box = np.int0(box)
cv2.drawContours(img_rotated_rect, [box], 0, (0, 0, 255), 2)
cv2.imshow('Rotated Rectangle', img_rotated_rect)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Get the rotation angle, width, and height from the rotated rectangle
center, (width, height), angle = rotated_rect

# Resize the overlay image to match the rotated rectangle
overlay_img_resized = cv2.resize(overlay_img, (int(width), int(height)))

# Add some transparent padding to the image so that it doesn't get cut off when it rotates
# (I'm not sure of the best math for pad, but overshooting is better than undershooting)
pad = int(max(width, height))
overlay_img_resized = cv2.copyMakeBorder(overlay_img_resized, pad, pad, pad, pad, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=(0, 0, 0, 0))

# Rotate the image by the angle
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((overlay_img_resized.shape[1] / 2, overlay_img_resized.shape[0] / 2), -angle, 1)
overlay_img_resized = cv2.warpAffine(overlay_img_resized, M, (overlay_img_resized.shape[1], overlay_img_resized.shape[0]))

# Show the resized overlay image
cv2.imshow('Resized Overlay Image', overlay_img_resized)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Overlay the rotated and resized image onto the original image,
# make sure to take pad into account, otherwise it will drift southeast
for i in range(overlay_img_resized.shape[0]):
    for j in range(overlay_img_resized.shape[1]):
        if overlay_img_resized[i, j][3] != 0:
            img[int(center[1]-height/2)-pad+i, int(center[0]-width/2)-pad+j] = overlay_img_resized[i, j][:3]

# Show the final image
cv2.imshow('Final Image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: thankyou for your explaination and answer

Comment: No problem @confuseman. Lmk if anything behaves strangely.